# Can I search in the list of available completions on commandline?

Tags: command-line, autocompletion, help-system

I have set some options to configure completion on the command line, for commands that support it.

I use the completion on the commandline very often with the `:help` command; That will be my example, but my question is about commandline completion in general.

If I have only a vague idea how the help topic, I type a substring I expect in the name, and press tab, showing a list of possible completions.
The list is often long enough to be not easily read through; this is an example where a search in the list would be useful.

In the screen shown below, the substring entered was `CTRL-W`. The first <kbd>Tab</kbd> listed the four columns. (Note it includes variants not starting with the substring.)
After pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, the second to last line was shown, repeating part of the table above it. Further <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses cycle through that line.

```
~                                                                          
~                                                                          
~                                                                          
:help CTRL-W
CTRL-W           CTRL-W_b         CTRL-W_g]        CTRL-W_CTRL-I
CTRL-W_+         CTRL-W_c         CTRL-W_g}        CTRL-W_CTRL-J
CTRL-W_-         CTRL-W_d         c_CTRL-W         CTRL-W_CTRL-K
CTRL-W_<         CTRL-W_f         i_CTRL-W         CTRL-W_CTRL-L
CTRL-W_=         CTRL-W_h         CTRL-W_gF        CTRL-W_CTRL-N
CTRL-W_>         CTRL-W_i         CTRL-W_gf        CTRL-W_CTRL-O
CTRL-W_]         CTRL-W_j         CTRL-W_<BS>      CTRL-W_CTRL-P
CTRL-W_^         CTRL-W_k         CTRL-W_<CR>      CTRL-W_CTRL-Q
CTRL-W__         CTRL-W_l         CTRL-W_<Up>      CTRL-W_CTRL-R
CTRL-W_}         CTRL-W_n         CTRL-W_bar       CTRL-W_CTRL-S
CTRL-W_F         CTRL-W_o         CTRL-W_<Down>    CTRL-W_CTRL-T
CTRL-W_H         CTRL-W_p         CTRL-W_<Left>    CTRL-W_CTRL-V
CTRL-W_J         CTRL-W_q         CTRL-W_CTRL-]    CTRL-W_CTRL-W
CTRL-W_K         CTRL-W_r         CTRL-W_CTRL-^    CTRL-W_CTRL-X
CTRL-W_L         CTRL-W_s         CTRL-W_CTRL-_    CTRL-W_CTRL-Z
CTRL-W_P         CTRL-W_t         CTRL-W_CTRL-B    CTRL-W_<Enter>
CTRL-W_R         CTRL-W_v         CTRL-W_CTRL-C    CTRL-W_<Right>
CTRL-W_S         CTRL-W_w         CTRL-W_CTRL-D    CTRL-W_g_CTRL-]
CTRL-W_T         CTRL-W_x         CTRL-W_CTRL-F    c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W
CTRL-W_W         CTRL-W_z         CTRL-W_CTRL-H
CTRL-W  CTRL-W_+  CTRL-W_-  CTRL-W_<  CTRL-W_=  CTRL-W_>  CTRL-W_]  CTRL-W_^  >
:help CTRL-W_<
```

The list of completions is often longer than one page, which causes a prompt for the next page.
In that case, the search would be even more helpful.

Comment: You can continue to add to your search and press tab again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`helpgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3Ahelpgrep) command:

```
:helpg[rep] {pattern}[@xx]
    Search all help text files and make a list of lines
    in which {pattern} matches.  Jumps to the first match.
    The optional [@xx] specifies that only matches in the
    "xx" language are to be found.
    You can navigate through the matches with the
    quickfix commands, e.g., :cnext to jump to the
    next one.  Or use :cwindow to get the list of
    matches in the quickfix window.
```

By default, it opens the first match. You can use `:clist` to see the list of all matches:

```
:cl
 1 cmdline.txt:111 col 11: *c_CTRL-W*
 2 cmdline.txt:112 col 1: CTRL-W          Delete the |word| before the cursor.  This depends on the
 3 cmdline.txt:138 col 22: <C-C>).  A <BS> or CTRL-W could still end the command line
 4 cmdline.txt:171 col 8: CTRL-R CTRL-W                           *c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W* *c_<C-R>_<C-W>*
 5 cmdline.txt:177 col 4: CTRL-W  the Word under the cursor
 6 cmdline.txt:181 col 44: currently displayed match is used.  With CTRL-W the part of
 7 cmdline.txt:190 col 44: CTRL-R CTRL-R {0-9a-z"%#:-=. CTRL-F CTRL-P CTRL-W CTRL-A}
 8 cmdline.txt:191 col 44: CTRL-R CTRL-O {0-9a-z"%#:-=. CTRL-F CTRL-P CTRL-W CTRL-A}
 9 editing.txt:320 col 5: |CTRL-W_CTRL-F|.
10 eval.txt:1033 col 52: \<xxx>  Special key named "xxx".  e.g. "\<C-W>" for CTRL-W.  This is for use
11 eval.txt:2288 col 33: <               The number can be used with |CTRL-W_w| and ":wincmd w"
12 eval.txt:6489 col 39: accessed window is returned (where |CTRL-W_p| goes to).
13 eval.txt:6492 col 32: The number can be used with |CTRL-W_w| and ":wincmd w"
14 hebrew.txt:105 col 10: cursor.  CTRL-W and CTRL-U also work in the opposite direction.  <BS>, CTRL-W
15 index.txt:16 col 28: 2.2. Window commands                    |CTRL-W|
16 index.txt:91 col 4: |i_CTRL-W|      CTRL-W          delete word before the cursor
17 index.txt:210 col 2: |CTRL-W|        CTRL-W {char}      window commands, see |CTRL-W|
18 index.txt:502 col 27: 2.2 Window commands                                             *CTRL-W*
19 index.txt:506 col 2: |CTRL-W_CTRL-B| CTRL-W CTRL-B      same as "CTRL-W b"
20 index.txt:507 col 2: |CTRL-W_CTRL-C| CTRL-W CTRL-C      same as "CTRL-W c"
21 index.txt:508 col 2: |CTRL-W_CTRL-D| CTRL-W CTRL-D      same as "CTRL-W d"
22 index.txt:509 col 2: |CTRL-W_CTRL-F| CTRL-W CTRL-F      same as "CTRL-W f"
23 index.txt:510 col 3: CTRL-W CTRL-G      same as "CTRL-W g .."
-- More --
```

It is certainly not the same as searching just through the tags, but might be useful.